# Using passport-google-oauth2 authentication in server - client app

Tags: graphql, passport.js, react-apollo, google-authentication, passport-google-oauth

I have a TypeOrm/React app connected with mongodb database, where server is on port 4000, and client is on port 3000.
On client I created file googleAuth:

```
import passport from 'passport';
import {User} from './entity/User';
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;

const googleOptions = {
  clientID: process.env.clientID,
  clientSecret: process.env.clientSecret,
  callbackURL: 'http://localhost:4000/auth/google/callback',
  profileFields: ['id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name'],
};

const googleCallback = (_accessToken: any, _refreshToken: any, profile: any, done: any) => {
  const matchingUser = User.findOne({googleId: profile.id});

  if (matchingUser) {
    done(null, matchingUser);
    return;
  }

  const newUser = {
    googleId: profile.id,
    firstName: profile.name.givenName,
    lastName: profile.name.familyName,
    email: profile.emails && profile.emails[0] && profile.emails[0].value
  };
  User.create(newUser);
  done(null, newUser);
}

export const googleAuth = () => passport.use(new GoogleStrategy(
  googleOptions,
  googleCallback
));
```

My index.ts(server) file looks like this:

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import {createConnection} from "typeorm";
import "dotenv/config"
import express from "express";
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";
import { buildSchema } from "type-graphql";
import cors from "cors";
import { PostResolver } from "./resolvers/PostResolver";
import { UserResolver } from "./resolvers/UserResolver";
import path from 'path';
import passport from "passport";
import { googleAuth} from './googleAuth';


(async () => {
 
    await createConnection();

    googleAuth();
    passport.serializeUser(function(user: any, done: any) {
      done(null, user);
    });
    
    passport.deserializeUser(function(user: any, done: any) {
      done(null, user);
    });

      const app = express();

      app.use(cors());

      app.use(passport.initialize());

      app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['email'] }));
      
      app.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', {
        successRedirect: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
        failureRedirect: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
      }));
  
    const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
      schema: await buildSchema({
        resolvers: [ PostResolver, UserResolver ]
      }),
      context: ({ req }) => ({
        getUser: () => req.user,
        logout: () => req.logout()
  })
  // context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res })
});

apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app });


app.use(express.static('public'));


app.get('*', (_, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../public', 'index.html'))
});


const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));

})();
```

My UserResolver:

```
import {
  Resolver,
  Query,
  Ctx
} from "type-graphql";
import { User } from "../entity/User";
import { MyContext } from '../MyContext';
import { ExpressContext } from "apollo-server-express/dist/ApolloServer";


@Resolver()
export class UserResolver {

  @Query(() => [User])
  users() {
    return User.find();
  }

  @Query(() => String)
  getUser(@Ctx() { req }: ExpressContext) {
    console.log(req);
    return `your user id is: ${req.user}`;
  }
}
```

In https://console.developers.google.com in credenatials I add
Authorised JavaScript origins: http://localhost:4000

In Authorised redirect URIs: http://localhost:4000/auth/google/callback

I can log in, but I can't get any data. I know that it's very messy code, but I need to organize this and rewrite it.
First, I want to know what domains and redirect should I add in my credentials.
Second is to configure server.
Third to create UserResolvers.
Fourth to get data with client.